# HttpClient SendAsync no error or data returned

Tags: dotnet-httpclient

```
  var client = new HttpClient();

            HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://api.stubhubsandbox.com/login"),

            };

            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Host", "api.stubhubsandbox.com");
            httpRequestMessage.Content = new StringContent(finalParameters);

            httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue(ContentType);
            httpRequestMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength = 80;
            httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", Authorization);


            Console.WriteLine(httpRequestMessage.ToString());

            var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).ContinueWith(respTask =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}", respTask.Result);
            });

            Console.ReadLine();
```

I have my fiddler open and I did not see my request has been sent. It did not return or throw any exceptions?
It looks somehow I can not invoke my call over https?

Comment: You don't need to set the host or the Content Length headers.  I don't see anything else wrong though.  I would suggest not doing ToString on the RequestMessage.  If that causes the stream to be read then that might mess up sending the payload.